# Getting stated with Gitlab CI/CD and dotnet

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to get started with our company's installation of gitlab. My script so far is somewhat simple, just to find out if dotnet can be used. So far it don't seem so. Every example I find online makes it seem like a script like this should run out of the box.

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest

stages:
  - "build"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet
```

So I get following output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.5.0 (ece86343)
on Dedicated Shared Runner 5f5c4004
Preparing the "shell" executor 00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on gitlab-ci-runners...
Getting source from Git repository 00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Bestehendes Git-Repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/5f5c4004/0/mfriese/sandbox/.git/ neuinitialisiert
Checking out cd3bccae as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
$ dotnet
bash: Zeile 112: dotnet: Befehl nicht gefunden
Cleaning up file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Basically saying `dotnet` is not here. I though using the correct image will provide required executables. What could be the problem here?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Actually the problem was a missing runner for Docker containers. After adding a tag for docker (such runner must be configured and available) it worked fine.

Comment: You can add an answer (and accept your own answer) illustrating what was missing: that will help others.